# How can I verify data passed from browser DApps to metamask?

Tags: metamask

I'm new to the world of web3, and learning interaction between dApps frontend and metamask.

Are there any tools (chrome extentions or other tool) to "sniff" the communication between dApps and metamask (Chrome extention)?

For instance, at pancakeswap, when I try to click "stake" button.

1. pancakeswap page (dApp frontend) will send multiple variables (such as destination contract address, stake data such as number of token to stake) TO metamask
2. metamask receive the data and ask if its okay to sign the transaction
3. metamask will send the transaction

I want to verify what kind of data is sent to metamask (between process 1 and 2).

Comment: the tool is blockchain. All the transactions are on the chain.